# Lightview 3 - close lightview and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript

I am using Lightview 3 for a gallery type effect.
I am trying to emulate the effect the 'cross' Close icon does with a simple text link -

ie. if i click the cross it closes and redirects to another page, how do I emulate this on an actual text link.

http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/lightview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it..

```
<a href='javascript:window.parent.Lightview.hide();'>Close Me</a>
```